# how to get row id and value of dropdown from gridview on drop change events

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am binding data on  grid view using the store procedure , there is drop-down(status ) inside the gridview ,  when the user the change the drop-down(value will be changed ) it will be updating the database ..

Problem: Now How i get the id of a particular row and drop-down value using j query .. 
I want to update  the  record using Ajax and web method(client requirement )

Please help

Comment: You should be posting the relevant markup and change event code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elmID = $("#DRopDown_ID").find("option:selected").attr('id')
```

Comment: and .val() to get the value of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
function ddlChanged(ddl)
{  
  var ddlValue = $(ddl).val();
  var tr = $(ddl).closest('tr');
}
```

In your gridview

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlStatus" runat="server" onchange="ddlChanged(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnect"].ToString());

    SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new SqlDataAdapter();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (!IsPostBack)

        {

            DataSet ds=new DataSet ();

            ds = ddlist("Select * from UserDetails");

            Grid_viewprofile.DataSource = ds;

            Grid_viewprofile.DataBind();

        }
    }

    protected void Grid_viewprofile_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 

    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Close")    
        {   

        //    Panel1.Visible = false; 

        }  

        if (e.CommandName == "Move")       
        {

            GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

            DropDownList lstuserName = (DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("ddl_groub");

            Response.Write("Selected Value : " + lstuserName.SelectedValue + " " + "Selected Item : " + lstuserName.SelectedItem.Text);  



        }

    }  


    public  DataSet   ddlist(string Qry)

    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new SqlDataAdapter(Qry, sqlcon);

        sqladp.Fill(ds);

        return ds;

    }

    protected void Grid_viewprofile_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

        {

            DropDownList  ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl_groub");

            ddl.DataSource = ddlist("Select * from UserDetails");

            ddl.DataTextField = "UserName";

            ddl.DataValueField = "ID";

            ddl.DataBind();

            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

        } 

    }
}
```

Client Side

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid_viewprofile" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"  



        runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="1" 



    AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="Grid_viewprofile_RowCommand" 

        onrowdatabound="Grid_viewprofile_RowDataBound">

    <Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" /> 

<asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" /> 

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Profile_Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_groub" runat="server">

        </asp:DropDownList>



        <asp:Button ID="btn_move" runat="server" Text="Move to group"  CommandName="Move" />

        <asp:Button ID="btn_close" runat="server" Text="Close"  CommandName="Close"/>

    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```